# Start DLL Process not working

Tags: java, dll, process, runtime

I want to run Shadowplay using Java.

If I run this command in the cmd it works fine.

```
C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe C:\\Windows\\system32\\nvspcap64.dll,ShadowPlayEnable
```

I tried in Java, but I get "Module not found".

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe C:\\Windows\\system32\\nvspcap64.dll,ShadowPlayEnable");
```

But if I remove the comma after .dll it works.
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the command and arguments in an array, like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe", "C:\\Windows\\system32\\nvspcap64.dll,ShadowPlayEnable"});
```

You could also try using `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe", "C:\\Windows\\system32\\nvspcap64.dll,ShadowPlayEnable");
pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] cmd = {"C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe", "C:\\Windows\\system32    \\nvspcap64.dll,ShadowPlayEnable"}; // Use an array
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```